# Body padding not applied to background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing a padding for my body tag like this because I am using a nav bar fixed top. I want the nav bar to always stay on top.

```
body {
   padding-top: 70px;
}
```

Now I want to add a background image to the body and want it to cover the entire screen. So I do this.

```
body {
   background: url(background.jpg);
   background-size: cover;
}
```

But the problem is that the nav bar covers parts of the image, the 70px padding is not working on the background image. Please help fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position the background 70px down using the offsets available in `background-position`

[**Background-Position @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300);
  background-position: top 70px center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, background does cover the padding, yes.

So one possible solution would be to use [background-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-origin) to tell the browser the background should start in the upper left of the content, rather than the padding area.

```css
html {background:white; height:100%}
body {
  box-sizing:border-box; min-height:100%;
  padding-top:70px;
  background: url(http://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300);
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

This one would have the advantage of being dynamic; i.e. you wouldn't need to change its value if changed the value of the padding.